# Bash - use variable in perl regex together with matching groups

Tags: regex, bash, perl, variables, for-loop

this is my first post on stackoverflow, please forgive me if I missed something important.
I am currently stuck with the follwing issue. The goal is, to replace port numbers dynamically based on a filelist I prepared with `find`. All of the ports in those files, start with the number "4" and have 5 digits.

Now the tricky part, I am replacing only digit #2 and #3, and keep positions 1, 4 and 5. Examples:

```
old port in file: 40380, 40381
new port in file: 41580, 40381
```

I am working on Sun Solaris 5.10 therefore I prefer perl for inline replacements

Finally the key question: how can I combine $1 (group 1) + $PIN_PINNO + $3 (group 3) so that the result would be: 4**15**80

```
NEW_PINNO=15
LOGI=$HOME/filelist.txt

# port replacement
for file in `cat $LOGI`
do
    perl -pe 's/[\:\>\=]\s*(4)(\d{2})(\d{2})\b/$1${NEW_PINNO}$3/g' $file
done
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Post some more input, expected output. Also use `while read` instead of `for`

Comment: Why not just do it all in `perl`?

Comment: 123: thank you for your input/hint, i appreciate it
Sobrique: it is part of a bigger shell script we're using to rebuild environments, therefore i will be using bash as much as i can, also, i dont have any solid perl knowlege

Comment: In order to get the intial `for`working, I had to explicitly export the `NEW_PINNO` variable and then call it like this: `$1$ENV{NEW_PINNO}$3`

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -pse 's/ [:>=]\s* \K (\d)\d\d(\d\d) \b/$1$pin$2/gx' -- -pin="$new_pinno" file
```

- Your regex will match the [colon, greater than, equal sign] and the spaces, but you don't include them in the substitution. I'm using the `\K` directive to match those characters but then forget about them (ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions)
- I'm using the `-s` option to enable "rudimentary switch parsing" to pass the shell variable into perl without playing quoting games. (ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Testing

```
new_pinno=15
perl -pse 's/ [:>=]\s* \K (\d)\d\d(\d\d) \b/$1$pin$2/gx' -- -pin="$new_pinno" <<END
var1=40380
var2=40381
END
```

```
var1=41580
var2=41581
```

Notes

- you should not use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES in the shell, leave those to be reserved by the shell. One day, you'll use `PATH=something` and then  wonder why your script is broken.
- and @123's comment is valid. This is the safe way to read lines from a file:

  ```
  while read -r file; do
      perl ... "$file"
  done < "$LOGI"
  ```

  ref: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: thank you glenn, i will try this as soon as i am back at work again

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/[\:\>\=]\s*(4)(\d{2})(\d{2})\b/$1'${NEW_PINNO}'$3/g' $file
```

is ok.

Comment: Your answer could benefice from some explaination

Answer (score -1):

The difference between single and double quotes is how bash treats its variables. In single quotes it won't expand them, but when enclosed in double quotes it will. You can open & close quotes as much as you want in a command line argument. It's only if there is a space that is outside of a pair of quotes (single or double) that determines the start of a new argument.

So you close the single quote, have the bash variable which will be expanded and then re-open the single quote. Enclosing the variable in double quotes ensures that if there are any spaces in the variable they'll not split the argument.

```
perl -pe 's/[\:\>\=]\s*(4)(\d{2})(\d{2})\b/$1'"${NEW_PINNO}"'$3/g' $file
```

Comment: why would you ever do this instead of just passing the variable in as an env variable or argument.

Comment: @123 you can't pass it in as an argument because the `-p` option expects all the arguments to be filenames. Passing it in as an environment variable is an option I guess, but it's no less ugly a hack than the solution I've provided

Comment: yes you can, look up the shift function. Also it isn't an ugly hack, your way allows double interpretation of the variable, which allows arbitrary code to be run in perl as well as breaking if it contains the delimiter or any special characters. My solutions don't. Don't post bad code then try and defend it when you have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @123 I'm allowed to defend my answer, especially as i don't see it as bad code - it's perfectly normal to do this in a bash script to mix variables and single quoted text. If you have a (better) solution, surely you'd have posted it as an answer

Comment: Glenn jackson already posted the proper way to do it.  It is bad code though, and it definitely is not normal to embed bash variables/code inside a perl command. Your defence of doing so is nonsense and misleading to other users.