# replace string with an variable having special chars in it using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with below content:

```
$ cat file
my name is PARESH.
```

Need to replace `PARESH` with content of variable `$REPLACE_WORD" using Perl.

```
perl -pi -e "s/PARESH/$REPLACE_WORD/g"  file
```

Problem is variable `$REPLACE_WORD` has special characters in it.

```
$REPLACE_WORD="c@sc9ey"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash - use variable in perl regex together with matching groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346845/bash-use-variable-in-perl-regex-together-with-matching-groups)

Answer (score 4):

Perl interpolates scalars (`$foo`) and arrays (`@bar`) in double quotes `""`. If you use single quotes `''` instead, no interpolation happens.

```
$REPLACE_WORDS = 'c@sc9ey';
```

Note that hash variabels (`%baz`) are **not** interpolated.

Answer (score 1):

When using double quotes, then escape the special characters using `\`

```
$REPLACE_WORD = "c\@sc9ey";
```